# Regular expression in java to replace white spaces and a specific pattern

Tags: java, string, split, expression

Im a little noobie with regular expressions.
I have a String like that:

```
"aaa - bbb - ccc --> ddd"
```

I need a regular expression that help me replace white spaces `" "` and the `"-->"`, so after replacing I will have that String as result:

```
"aaa-bbb-cccddd"
```

Some help please?

Comment: You probably don't need a regex, search info for string's replace() method

Comment: I didn't say it but what I am really doing is using that regular expression in the split method of String. :P

Answer (score 3):

Use an alternation (the pipe character `|` in regex is a logical "or"):

```
str = str.replaceAll(" |-->", "");
```

alternatively, since you don't need regex to find your search terms:

```
str = str.replace(" ", "").replace("-->", "");
```

which may be easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks man, I can´t vote you because Im new in the web. But thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one expression you could use this one:

```
String newOne = old.replaceAll("[ ]|(-->)", "");
```

this means: replace all `" "` OR `-->` with empty string.

But you have many alternatives:

```
"(-->)?[ ]?"
// or using + or * regular expression operators to capture more spaces in one match if you also have that case
"(-->)*[ ]*"
```

And if you know that your string has also a fixed format for `aaa`, `bbb`, etc. you can make a bigger expression in order to catch all in one go.

The parentheses in the first expression and square brackets around the space are options for you to see better the structure of the expression.